# Neo4j delete nodes that have more that one relationship between them

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to clear the database from wrong data.
I have nodes that have more than one relationship between each other and I am trying to delete those nodes.

An example of that would be:

```
(p:Person{id:'1'})-[r:SIBLING_OF]-(k:Person{id:'2'})
(p:Person{id:'1'})-[r:PARENT_OF]-(k:Person{id:'2'})
```

I have tried several queries but none of them were right.

Does anyone know what would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to delete the nodes, not just the relationships, right?

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:SIBLING_OF]-(p2:Person),
(p2)-[:PARENT_OF]-(p1)
DETACH DELETE p1, p2
```

You should probably do RETURN instead of DETACH DELETE first to ensure you're deleting the right ones.

Comment: This query works fine. Just one disadvantage is that I have many different relationships, so I would have to do this query for many different combinations

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more generic query to find and delete all pairs of nodes with more than one relationship between them you could try this:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r]-(p2:Person)
WITH p1, p2, count(r) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 1 and id(p1) < id(p2)
DETACH DELETE p1, p2
```